# Does make_shared do a default initialization (zero-init) for each member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, shared-ptr

Take an ordinary struct (or class) with Plain Old Data types and objects as members. Note that there is no default constructor defined.

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    double z;
    string str;
};
```

Now if I declare an instance f on the stack and attempt to print its contents:

```
{
    Foo f;
    std::cout << f.x << " " << f.y << " " << f.z << f.str << std::endl;
}
```

The result is garbage data printed for x, y, and z. And the string is default initialized to be empty.  **As expected.**

If I create an instance of a `shared_ptr<Foo>` using `make_shared` and print:

```
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> spFoo = make_shared<Foo>();
    cout << spFoo->x << " " << spFoo->y << " " << spFoo->z << spFoo->str << endl;
}
```

Then, x, y, and z are all `0`.  Which makes it appear that `shared_ptr` performs a default initialization (zero init) on each member after the object instance is constructed.  At least that's what I observe with Visual Studio's compiler.

Is this standard for C++?  Or would it be necessary to have an explicit constructor or explicit `={}` statement after instantiation to guarantee zero-init behavior across all compilers?

Comment: Practical question: do you want a *guarantee* that you can rely on this, or a *way to avoid it*?

Comment: The former. I wanted to make sure it was standard behavior such that it could be relied on across different compilers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you see e.g. [this `std::make_shared` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) you will see that

> The object is constructed as if by the expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, where `pv` is an internal `void*` pointer to storage suitable to hold an object of type `T`.

That means `std::make_shared<Foo>()` basically does `new Foo()`. That is, it [*value initializes*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the structure which leads to the zeroing of the non-class member variables.

Answer (score 9):

To be more precise, [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) employes [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) syntax,

> The object is constructed as if by the expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

For `Foo` with an empty initializer list, that means all its members with built-in type will be [zero-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization), and `std::string` will be [default-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).